# 1 object is dependent on another, but both dependent on a 3rd object

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a CreateNewGroupActivity in which there are 2 different custom LinearLayouts created.
Im using the MVP mosby framework and dagger2.
My problem is with the dependency injection.
Each layout is dependent on **DBManager** class, but **PlaceDetailsPresenter** is dependent on **TicketPresenter** class.

How can I construct the **proper dependency graph** so that I have only one instance of TicketPresenter, which is the **same instance** I can inject into **PlaceDetailsPresenter**?

Below is the code where I am at right now.
The @PerApp scope which provides the DBManager for the 2 presenters and @CreateNewGroupScope is the scope of the CreateNewGroupActivity.

```
@PerApp
@Component(modules = MyAppModule.class)
public interface MyAppComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication myApp);
    DBManager dbManager();
}

@Module
public class MyAppModule {
    private final MyApplication app;
    public MyAppModule(MyApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
    @Provides @PerApp MyApplication provideMyApp() {
        return app;
    }
    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return app;
    }
    @Provides
    @PerApp
    DBManager provideRealmDBManager() {
        return new DBManager();
    }
}

@Module
public class TicketModule {
    @Provides
    @CreateNewGroupScope
    public TicketPresenter provideTicketPresenter(DBManager dbManager) {
        return new TicketPresenter(dbManager);
    }
}

@CreateNewGroupScope
@Component(modules = TicketModule.class, dependencies = MyAppComponent.class)
public interface TicketComponent {
    void inject(TicketRelativeLayout ticketRelativeLayout);
    TicketPresenter presenter();
}


@Module
public class PlaceDetailsModule {
    @Provides 
    @CreateNewGroupScope
    public PlaceDetailsPresenter providePlaceDetailsPresenter(DBManager dbManager, TicketPresenter ticketPresenter) {
        return new PlaceDetailsPresenter(dbManager, ticketPresenter);
    }
}

@CreateNewGroupScope
@Component(modules = PlaceDetailsModule.class, dependencies = MyAppComponent.class)
public interface PlaceDetailsComponent extends TicketComponent{
    void inject(PlaceDetailsLayout placeDetailsLayout);
}
```

and the JAVA classes:

```
public class PlaceDetailsPresenter ...
   ...
   @Inject
    public PlaceDetailsPresenter(final DBManager dbManager, final TicketPresenter ticketPresenter) {
        this.dbManager = dbManager;
        this.ticketPresenter = ticketPresenter;
    }
...

public class PlaceDetailsLayout extends ...
    ...
    @Inject PlaceDetailsPresenter presenter;

    private void init() {
    PlaceDetailsComponent placeDetailsComponent = DaggerPlaceDetailsComponent.builder()
                .myAppComponent(MyApplication.getComponent(getContext()))
                .placeDetailsModule(new PlaceDetailsModule())
                .build();
        placeDetailsComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
public class TicketPresenter ...{
    @Inject
    public TicketPresenter(final DBManager dbManager) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ticketPresenter constructor");
        this.dbManager = dbManager;
    }
}
public class TicketRelativeLayout extends ...
    @Inject
    TicketPresenter presenter;  

    private void init() {   
        TicketComponent ticketComponent = DaggerTicketComponent.builder()
        .myAppComponent(MyApplication.getComponent(getContext()))
        .ticketModule(new TicketModule()).build();
    ticketComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Basically, this activity is about selecting the proper **ticket types** on a certain date in the TicketLayout for the **selected place** in PlaceDetailsLayout.
First, I select the **placetype** from the icon tabs, which determines what **places** I can choose from and it also fetches all the **available tickets** for this place.
Then in the TicketLayout I select the **date, hour, tickets**.
Selecting a **certain date**, populates the available hours and selecting the **preferred hour** lists all available **tickettypes** you can choose from.
So, if you select the dates or hours in the TicketLayout it has **no effect** on the other layout.
However, if you **change/select another place** in the PlaceDetailsLayout, then it will change the underlying **TicketLayout** completely with the related data(dates, hours, tickettypes).
Now, I have an **observable** for the place selecting event which delegates the **selected placeName** to the ticketPresenter so as to populate the TicketLayout with the **data belonging to this place**.
I have a DB table for the **Places**, and another one for the **Tickets**

and a screenshot from the not entirely implemented Activity:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3fdh.jpg

Comment: Why does one Presenter (PlaceDetailsPresenter) depends on another Presenter (TicketPresenter). Doesn't make much sense imho. Maybe both presenters depend on the same "Model" (business logic) like DBManager is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @sockeqwe: I have updated the description with more details so it would be clearer.

Comment: Two presenters should not depend on each other. The answer is `@Module(includes={PlaceDetailsModule.class})` by the way.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce:  "The answer is @Module(includes={PlaceDetailsModule.class}) by the way" - How do you mean this ? Should I put @Module(includes={TicketModule.class}) class PlaceDetailsModule { ..} ? or I don't quite understand.

Comment: Apparently I got confused and it's actually `@Module({includes=TicketModule.class})
public class PlaceDetailsModule {`